# How to determine if correlated errors are a result of using an incorrect functional form?

Tags: regression, independence, sandwich

Assume you have identified that the errors of a regression model are correlated.  How should you determine if this is a sign of using incorrect an functional form?  That is, a situation that should be addressed by changing the primary functional model, for example using a quadratic function.  Alternatively, how would you determine if you needed to utilize Newey-West standard errors, or adapt a univariate time series model (AR, MA etc.) instead? Can a set of general rules (no matter how rough and loose they be) be outlined for such cases?

Answer (score 1):

First of all applying linear regression may be flawed due to needed lag structures in the causals and very possibly anomalies in any series. The suggested approach is to form a Transfer Function (SARMAX) model and carefully augmenting the model with latent deterministic structure such as pulses /level-step shifts,seasonal pulses and/or local time trends) and then deal with possible non-constant error variance. Take a look at http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html and http://www.autobox.com/pdfs/TSAY.pdf
and http://www.autobox.com/pdfs/WHY-WE-FILTER.ppt .

Comment: It isn't clear the OP has an actual time-series in mind.

Comment: they alluded to possible time series remedies in the question so I assumed that they had time series/chronological data and the errors were correlated (auto-correlated is what I think they ere trying to say)

Comment: @ IrishStat Thank you for your answer. My question is general and, as @gung said, doesn’t address just an actual time series in a sense you have in mind, however your answer is helpful in some specific situations but don’t address the first part of my question. To put my question in a clearer context, assume it is just “how we can determine that identifying correlated errors in a regression model is a sign of using an incorrect functional form or not”?